# How to extrude two faces at the same time with opposite direction

Tags: modeling, extrude

I watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyQOz1WylJU&t=2076s) on youtube at 43:22 and I do not know how to extrude two faces at the same time with opposite. The first one to bottom and the second one to top. Is there any shortcut or the name of the function? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: select the faces > type E (for extrude) > type S (for scale) and X, Y or Z (depending on which direction). That's how i do this.

Comment: There's nothing at that timestamp but at 43:32 she just uses S > Z to scale in the Z direction as you can see by the vertical blue line while she's scaling although the 'Z' key doesn't seem to have been registered in the screencast keys image.

Comment: ( as @John Eason says  .. with 'Median Point' as the pivot ..)

Comment: Yes indeed. Others here have mentioned Extruding which hasn't actually been used at all at this time!

Comment: Select the faces you want, right click, and select "extrude faces along normals" (must be in face select mode).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alt+E and then select "Extrude Individual Faces" to extrude the selected Faces individually along their face normal.